# Is there any before page load event?

Tags: javascript

I need actually to show a div with activity indicator before the page is loaded?

Comment: You can put JavaScript anywhere on the page and it will be executed when the parser reaches it. Or you show the div from the beginning and hide it later.

Comment: Why not just render it as visible from the server? You can always hide it with JavaScript later.

Comment: Can't you just put that div first in the page source (and then possibly hide the rest of the page while it's loading as appropriate, using some inline script)?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the div on the page and hide it when the page loads. There's no need for an event..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JQuery? JQuery provides a `ready()` method that can (apparently) be used on any element.